# html/css parallax background doesnt work on Edge and IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, parallax, microsoft-edge

I have a problem with parallax. background-image just disappears on Edge and IE...
[screen from chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FKFwA.jpg)
[screen from edge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zkRFf.jpg)
Here's my html:

```
<div class="description-banner">
                    <p>PASJA, SZACUNEK, <span class="highlighted">PAMIĘĆ.</span></p>
                    <p>W kamieniarstwie Prekambr wkładamy całe swoje serca w każdy najmniejszy szlif.</p>
                    <p>Wiemy, że owoce naszej pracy upamiętniają osoby, które odeszły.</p>
                    <p>Wybierajac nas wybierasz szacunek dla swoich bliskich!</p>
                </div>
```

AND CSS:

```
.description-banner {
  background-image: url('../img/nagrobki-prekambr.jpg');
  height: 400px; 
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: 30% 20%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  margin-bottom: 80px;
  text-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);

}
```

I also used some jQuery plugins like smooth scrolling on mouse scrolling and smooth scrolling to anchors from w3schools.
Huge thanks for help in advance!

Comment: Your markup does not show a minimal, complete representation of the problem: [mcve]

Comment: please give me some more advise 'cause I think example is minimal, complete and verifable as well

Comment: You could use the developer tools to see what's going on with the CSS. Simply press F12. Works in most desktop browsers on Windows.

Comment: i used there are no errors

Answer (score 0):

Fixed - i had to change the image for any other one. I dont know why but it works now.